# Why does my laptop get very hot when using live Knoppix DVD?

Tags: knoppix

Summary:

I want to use the live knoppix DVD (KNOPPIX_V7.0.2DVD-2012-05-30-EN.iso) to
do a virus check on my laptop and then to do some repartitioning.

After booting the live DVD, at the moment I'm just leaving the laptop sat doing
nothing, while I work on another computer. But after half an hour to an hour,
the laptop gets disturbingly hot to the touch near the fan underneath (see Full
Details below for exact location). It feels about 50 or 60 degrees C to the
touch.

My question:

Is there a power-management program (or whatever) that isn't running on the DVD,
but should be? What can I do to stop the laptop overheating?

On this same laptop, I also have the live DVD installed on the hard drive. And
when I use it from the hard drive, there is no overheating. The area near the
fan is then about 25 to 30 degrees C to the touch.

Full Details:

The problem is repeatable - every time I use the laptop booted from the live
DVD, the overheating occurs.

The fan is about 2 1/2 inches in from the left edge of the laptop, roughly under
number-key "3" on the keyboard (above the qwerty keys).

The hot area extends from the fan to the left edge of the laptop, and down
towards the front of the laptop by about 4 inches.

The laptop is an Acer Aspire 5755G.

Comment: Is the DVD continuously spinning when this happens?

Comment: Check the CPU governor in use.  Some do not scale back the CPU speed when there is little or no load. It is possible to change the governor dynamically.  The available governors and their location in the file system may changes depending on the kernel.

Comment: Compare `dmesg` output for DVD/harddisk for differences, esp. wrt to CPU governor, power control etc.

Answer (score 0):

The heat is completely normal.  As long as the  software managing the actual CPU, GPU, Motherboard and chassis temps.  is running and is showing everything in the green. Then you have nothing to worry about.  I have Dells, Lenovo's that all his 50C and are scalding hot.   (especially the Lenovo's).  This is the new norm, hot means things are working.

Try running off the battery (albeit won't be long), but you might find that it's a little cooler due to the system management reducing performance to save battery life.

Comment: Hot means it is wasting energy (unless it is really doing some hard computations).